# split and display fetched data from databse in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, db2

I'm getting trouble while splitting and displaying the data which i have fetched from db2.

```
conn.query("SELECT * from eman_154.sinfo_6 WHERE EMPEMAIL ='"+result.email+"'",
                            function(err, data) {
                                if (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                                cn.close();
                                } 
                                else {
                                    req.session.email =result.email;
                                    req.session.authenticated = result.authenticated;
                                    console.log(req.session.authenticated);
                                    console.log(data.sfirstname); // i want to display the empname from data array
                                    res.redirect('/profile');;

                                }
                    });
```

values in console for data look like

```
[ { SID: '123456',
SFIRSTNAME: 'firstNAME',
SLASTNAME: 'lastNAME',} ]
```

in console when i use `console.log(data)`

thanks in advance

Comment: And what are you expecting to get? There's isn't really a proper question here !

Comment: @adeneo i'm expecting that when i use `console.log(data.sfirstname)` it will show firstNAME in console however it is showing undefined

Comment: `sfirstname` != `SFIRSTNAME`.

Comment: @Kenney i tried in both ways it shows undefined

Comment: Ah - note the `[ ]` around the output: it is an array. `console.log(data[0].SFIRSTNAME)` should work as you expect.

Comment: ya right i got that, that started working

Comment: thanx, can you please add this as an answer